# How to store a text in a file, to retrieve it later in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am doing a command that if you mention a user, *the discord bot stores the mentioned user name in a file* (I'm using **discord.js and node.js**). This is my piece of **code:**

```
const prv = require('C:/Users/Kikkiu/Desktop/prova.txt')
  const user = message.mentions.users.first();
   if (message.content.startsWith('.teammate')) {
     message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
     message.reply(`Hai aggiunto ${user} al tuo terzetto!`);
     fs.appendFileSync('C:/Users/Kikkiu/Desktop/prova.txt', JSON.stringify(user.tag))
   }
```

My problem here is that I can't figure out how to store the `user.tag`, so I can retrieve it later.

**What isn't working?**
This is the `user.tag` stored in the `.txt` file:

> "Kikkiu2#5629"

I want something more like this: `"By Kikkiu#3772": "Kikkiu2#5629"`.
The first part can be like this: `const msga = message.author.id;` and then

```
fs.appendFileSync('C:/Users/Kikkiu/Desktop/prova.txt', JSON.stringify(msga : user.tag))
```

Am I right?

Comment: What isn't working like you want?

Comment: This is the `user.tag` stored in the .txt file: `Kikkiu2#5629`. I want something more like this: `Kikkiu#3772: Kikkiu2#5629`. The first part can be like this: `const msga = message.author.id;` and then `fs.appendFileSync('C:/Users/Kikkiu/Desktop/prova.txt', JSON.stringify(msga : user.tag))`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like `let prova = fs.readFile(...)` (I'll let you research the function in the fs docs) and then split it appropriately

EDIT: oops sorry, I meant to send that as a comment, I'm not used to stack overflow on mobile yet

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using template literals?

```
fs.appendFileSync('C:/Users/Kikkiu/Desktop/prova.txt', JSON.stringify(`By ${msga} :${user.tag}`))
```

Comment: It works, the bot doesn't crash, but how can I take the string that the bot wrote in the file (for example `if (message.content === '.prova') {
     message.reply(`${prv}`)
   }`

Comment: Sorry, can reformulate? I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: I want the bot to send a message with the text that it wrote in the prova.txt file.